# How can I get the latest Thunderbird releases on my Mint 18.2 (= Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, thunderbird, ppa

I use Linux Mint 18.2, and I want to use the latest Mozilla Thunderbird version. I was assuming I should be able to find a PPA, but somehow I'm not able to...

I'm looking at: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam and I'm only seeing a Beta PPA. Betas are nice, but I want the release please. Am I missing something? Do I just need to monitor the release schedule myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Thunderbird](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/) Ubuntu package page shows that the latest version (52.2.1) is available as a security update for many supported released of Ubuntu, including 16.04, so you should be able to install it in Mint 18.2 as-is. `apt-cache policy thunderbird` should show 1:52.2.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 as the candidate version.

I expect future releases of Thunderbird will continue to be made available in this manner, so you shouldn’t have to configure any additional repositories or monitor releases yourself.